# Warning using SoapClient in php

Tags: php

when i using soapclient in php a warning message show to me.and web page load in a long time.this is my code

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$sms_client = new SoapClient('http://87.107.121.54/post/send.asmx?wsdl', array('encoding'=>'UTF-8'));

$parameters['username'] = "demo";
$parameters['password'] = "demo";
$parameters['to'] = "912...";
$parameters['from'] = "1000..";
$parameters['text'] ="test";
$parameters['isflash'] =false;

echo $sms_client->SendSimpleSMS2($parameters)->SendSimpleSMS2Result;

?>
```

I check username and password and they correct.when i run above code this error display.

```
Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient(http://87.107.121.54/post/send.asmx?wsdl) [soapclient.soapclient]: failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /home/keyhanfa/public_html/test/test.php on line 5

Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient() [soapclient.soapclient]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://87.107.121.54/post/send.asmx?wsdl" in /home/keyhanfa/public_html/test/test.php on line 5
```

Comment: Maybe it's because `http://87.107.121.54/post/send.asmx?wsdl` is not accessible?

Comment: when i enter that url separately in browser a XML file displayed

Comment: Are you using localhost? Because I can't access `http://87.107.121.54/post/send.asmx?wsdl`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP SoapClient times out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800215/php-soapclient-times-out)

Comment: i put my code in test.php in webhosting and run my code with this url
www.mysite.com/test.php